# select option remove() method on removing multiple options

Tags: javascript

I'm having a select box which contains 17 values/options.

```
<select id="_class" name="_class">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="1">PREKG</option>
    <option value="2">LKG</option>
    <option value="3">UKG</option>
    <option value="4">I</option>
    <option value="5">II</option>
    <option value="6">III</option>
    <option value="7">IV</option>
    <option value="8">V</option>
    <option value="9">VI</option>
    <option value="10">VII</option>
    <option value="11">VIII</option>
    <option value="12">IX</option>
    <option value="13">X</option>
    <option value="14">XI</option>
    <option value="15">XII</option>
    <option value="16">XIII</option>                              
</select>
```

Now, I'm trying to remove the option from 5 to 8. For that, I'm using the following JavaScript code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var _class = document.getElementById("_class");
 for(var i=1; i < _class.length;i++) {
   if(i>=5 && i<=8) {
     _class.remove(i);
   }
 }
</script>
```

But, I'm not getting the expected result, because every time as if the for loop runs, the order of the option is getting changed.

How can I get the desired result?

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Gy8j8/) I've attached the Fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

By iterating through the options incrementally, the indices of the options after an option that is removed will be reduced by one as soon as the option is removed (ie: removing the option at index 5 causes options 6 and above to now be indexed as options 5 and above).

To cater for this, reverse the order of the loop to count downwards:

```
var _class = document.getElementById("_class");

for(var i=Math.min(_class.options.length, 8); i >= 5; i--) {
  _class.remove(i);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Gy8j8/2/

Answer (score 1):

A simpler example: remove number 2 to 4 of a list of 6:
In this list, the digit represents the INDEX in the array:

- 1) one
- 2) two
- 3) three
- 4) four
- 5) five
- 6) six

now if I remove number 2, the rest of the items get a new index:

- 1) one
- 2) three
- 3) four
- 4) five
- 5) six

if I remove number 3 next, I actually hit for:

- 1) one
- 2) three
- 3) five
- 4) six

There's a very simple trick to avoid this:  remove in reverse order:
in this example (removing 2 to 4) we remove 4 first:

- 1) one
- 2) two
- 3) three
- 4) four
- 5) five
- 6) six

after removing four, only the indexes higher than four changed, and
they don't matter to us:

- 1) one
- 2) two
- 3) three
- 4) five
- 5) six

now we can remove three:

- 1) one
- 2) two
- 3) five
- 4) six

In programing terms this means turning the for loop around:

```
 for(var i=8; i >= 5;i--) {
    _class.remove(i);
 }
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/bjelline/XQH54/

p.s. as you can see, I also changed the loop to only touch
the indexes we really need.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late, but I had the same issue. Here's my solution.
And thanks @steveukx, your explanation helped me out!

```
function remove(el) {
    for(var i=el.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
        if(el[i].selected)
            el.remove(i);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I faced the same problem. i am pasting my solution.
in fubbe answer these is some problem if user is trying to send higher index first and lower index subsequently ..thereby i am aorting the arguments passed to ensure that indexes (received through parameters) are sorted in ascending order first then our loop will be in reverse order to delete the indexes.

```
HTMLSelectElement.prototype.removeIndexes = removeIndexes;
function removeIndexes(){
  var res = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).sort(function(a, b){return     a-b})
  alert(res)
  for (var i=res.length-1;i>=0;i--){
     (function(self,indx){
      self.remove(indx);  
     })(this,res[i])
  }
}
var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
x.removeIndexes(2,3)

 //------- Another way----------------
 HTMLSelectElement.prototype.removeIndexes = removeIndexes;
 function removeIndexes(){
   var self = this;
   var res = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).sort(function(a, b)     {return b-a}).map(function(indx){
   alert(indx)
   self.remove(indx);
 })


 }
 var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
 x.removeIndexes(2,0,1)
```

Hope this helps

Kind Regards
Gaurav Khurana